# Spinner causes null pointer exception

Tags: android, view

I have tried all suggestions in similar questions but I can't fix it. A Spinner view is giving me a null pointer exception. The exception occurs at the following line: `spinner.setAdapter(adapter);`. I suspect it has something to do with it not being inflated correctly. The String array should not be the problem. I have also tried an almost exact copy of the code here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html.

I have also cleaned my code multiple times. Can anyone find the problem?

Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.themeSpinner);
        String[] themesArray = new String[]{"Dark Holo Theme"};


        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, themesArray);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/themeSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/screenDimSwitch"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

> 12-28 16:22:04.011: E/AndroidRuntime(12269): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-28 16:22:04.011: E/AndroidRuntime(12269):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.sudokuandroidprobeersel/com.example.sudokuandroidprobeersel.SettingsActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 12-28 16:22:04.011:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12269):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
>   12-28 16:22:04.011: E/AndroidRuntime(12269):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
>   12-28 16:22:04.011: E/AndroidRuntime(12269):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127) 12-28
>   16:22:04.011: E/AndroidRuntime(12269):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
>   12-28 16:22:04.011: E/AndroidRuntime(12269):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 12-28
>   16:22:04.011: E/AndroidRuntime(12269):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 12-28 16:22:04.011:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12269):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512) 12-28
>   16:22:04.011: E/AndroidRuntime(12269):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-28
>   16:22:04.011: E/AndroidRuntime(12269):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 12-28 16:22:04.011:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12269):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:984)
>   12-28 16:22:04.011: E/AndroidRuntime(12269):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751) 12-28
>   16:22:04.011: E/AndroidRuntime(12269):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 12-28 16:22:04.011:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12269): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   12-28 16:22:04.011: E/AndroidRuntime(12269):  at
>   com.example.sudokuandroidprobeersel.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:80)
>   12-28 16:22:04.011: E/AndroidRuntime(12269):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465) 12-28
>   16:22:04.011: E/AndroidRuntime(12269):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
>   12-28 16:22:04.011: E/AndroidRuntime(12269):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
>   12-28 16:22:04.011: E/AndroidRuntime(12269):  ... 11 more

**Update:**

The object that causes the null pointer exception is the Spinner, not the adapter. R.id.themeSpinner is correctly referenced in R though.

Comment: can you point out which line is SettingsActivity.java:80

Comment: is the line `spinner.setAdapter(adapter);` as I stated above.

Comment: Debug the project and check which one is null: adapter or spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all that you say is true
(1. its certainly the spinner, 2. it throws the nullpointer at spinner.setAdapter(adapter);)

Then we can safely state that indeed the inflating goes wrong.

Are you sure you're using the correct layout in  setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);? 
Is the spinner not included from some other layout?

Comment: Yes I am completely sure. The spinner is definitely included from R.layout.activity_settings.

Comment: Oh apparently there WAS a second activity_settings.xml file that I wasn't notified about.

Answer (score 0):

Right, you should debug it and you will se that the spinner object is null, it can only be this. You should clean your project and reinstall the app again, it should work then, it happens sometimes with layouts.

Comment: As I said in my question, I have already tried cleaning the project. (And reinstalling the app of course)

Comment: Then maybe you are referencing the wrong layout? Come on, that should work usually, try changing the name themeSpinner to another name, maybe the name is causing trouble. An put a breakpoint after Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.themeSpinner); to see if its still null after changing the name.

Comment: changing the name of the spinner, cleaning and reinstalling doesn't work. Also, R.id.mSpinner is a correct ID, it is correctly referenced in R.

Comment: Then uninstall the app, close the project, take a break and then make a new layout file and try it again, you know it should work, there is nothing strange here, and test it on another device/emulator.